# Can't define Android notification app in RN App

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having some trouble getting the **notification icon** or the **status icon** (I'm not sure what it's officially called) defined for our React-Native-built Android app.

When sending out push notifications, Android is taking the actual app icon and using that as the notification icon, resulting in this experience.

On the lockscreen:

[image]

and from the notifications slide-down:

[image]

Has anyone managed to add the notification (I'm aware it should be a white image on a transparent background) to a React Native app?

Comment: make sure your notification icon doesn't contain background

Comment: check https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/

Comment: Yup, I've been using an actual notification example image provided by one of the Android Sample Apps